# How to create and require completion of a subset of several tasks Workflow Foundation?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, workflow-foundation

I have a process that requires approval from any two people out of a group of four or five. I'd like to create a task assigned to each person, and after two of those tasks are complete, delete the remaining tasks and move on with the workflow.

Is there a way to create multiple tasks with a single `CreateTask` activity? Also, I'm still fairly new to WorkFlow, so if I store the `TaskIDs` in an array, can I iterate over them to delete the remaining tasks after the fact?

Or am I going about this entirely the wrong way? I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if they apply to Sharepoint, but check these posts from Matt Winkler:

- [Different Execution Patterns with WF (or, Going beyond Sequential and State Machine)](http://blogs.msdn.com/mwinkle/archive/2007/05/24/different-execution-patterns-with-wf-or-going-beyond-sequential-and-state-machine.aspx)
- [Implementing the N of M Pattern in WF](http://blogs.msdn.com/mwinkle/archive/2007/06/27/implementing-the-n-of-m-pattern-in-wf.aspx)

I think that the second post describes exactly your case.